# I don't comprehend why Scilab is giving me "syntax error, unexpected ;"

Tags: matrix, scilab

Well, I got this Newton's Method for multiple variables code that was modified by me to function with 4 variables instead of 2, but I keep getting the error

> Syntax error, unexpected ;

referencing line 9 which is the Jacobian matrix from the partial derivatives of the equations on function F. Every " " is another column and every ";" is another line.

```
clear;clc
function z=F(p1,p2,p3,p4) 
    z(1)=0.3*(500-p1)^0.5-0.2*(p1-p2)^0.5+0.2*(p1-p3)^0.5
    z(2)=0.2*(p1-p2)^0.5-0.1*(p2-p4)^0.5+0.2*(p2-p3)^0.5
    z(3)=0.1*(p1-p3)^0.5-0.2*(p3-p2)^0.5+0.1*(p3-p4)^0.5
    z(4)=0.1*(p2-p4)^0.5+0.1*(p3-p4)^0.5-0.2*(p4)^0.5
endfunction
function z=J(p1,p2,p3,p4) //Jacobiano
    z=[-0.3/(2*sqrt(500-p1))-0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p2))+0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p3)) 0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p2)) -0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p3)) 0;0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p2)) -0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p2))-0.1/(2*sqrt(p2-p4))+0.2/(2*sqrt(p2-p3) -0.2/(2*sqrt(p2-p3)) -0.1/(2*sqrt(p2-p4));0.1/(2*sqrt(p1-p3)) 0.2/(2*sqrt(p3-p2)) -0.1/(2*sqrt(p1-p3))-0.2/(2*sqrt(p3-p2))+0.1(2*sqrt(p3-p4)) -0.1/(2*sqrt(p3-p4));0 0.1/(2*sqrt(p2-p4)) 0.1/(2*sqrt(p3-p4)) -0.1/(2*sqrt(p2-p4))-0.1/(2*sqrt(p3-p4))-0.2/(2*sqrt(p4))]
endfunction
```

The code doesn't end here, but the error is certainly in the format I used in the 4x4 Jacobian matrix or in the function itself, I just don't get why is wrong.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close a parenthesis in column 191 of line 9, and you also forgot an operator on column 319.

If you're creating a matrix in which the elements are results of operations, you'd better use commas instead of blank spaces to separate them. You should also be using `...` to break the matrix definition in more than one line to improve readability. Your Jacobian function would be a lot easier to debug if it were written like this:

```
function z=J(p1,p2,p3,p4) //Jacobiano
    z=[-0.3/(2*sqrt(500-p1))-0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p2))+0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p3)),...
        0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p2)),...
       -0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p3)),...
        0;...
        ...
        0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p2)),...
       -0.2/(2*sqrt(p1-p2))-0.1/(2*sqrt(p2-p4))+0.2/(2*sqrt(p2-p3),...
       -0.2/(2*sqrt(p2-p3)),...
       -0.1/(2*sqrt(p2-p4));...
        ...
        0.1/(2*sqrt(p1-p3)),...
        0.2/(2*sqrt(p3-p2)),...
       -0.1/(2*sqrt(p1-p3))-0.2/(2*sqrt(p3-p2))+0.1(2*sqrt(p3-p4)),...
       -0.1/(2*sqrt(p3-p4));...
        ...
        0,...
        0.1/(2*sqrt(p2-p4)),...
        0.1/(2*sqrt(p3-p4)),...
       -0.1/(2*sqrt(p2-p4))-0.1/(2*sqrt(p3-p4))-0.2/(2*sqrt(p4))]
endfunction
```

In this style, your mistakes can be easily spotted: notice the missing `)` in line 8, and the missing `/` in line 14.